# can't add System.Linq reference to website application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I can't seem to fingure out why i can't add a reference to the .net namespace `System.Linq`.   I used aspnet_regiis to check if i have the latest version of asp.net installed :

```
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -lv
    2.0.50727.0    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
    4.0.30319.0    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
    4.0.30319.0    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

I've also tried adding a reference to `System.Core`, but still i can't reference the `System.Linq` dll.

Also in my web.config, under

```
      <assemblies>
           <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
```

as iv'e mentioned before the refrences to System.Core and System.Data.Linq Exist in my website application :    under  Property Page -> references i could clearly see the exsiting refrences i added them again just in case and still i can't use the 
System.Linq or System.Linq.Data  NameSpaces .

Any ideas how i could reference the System.Linq dll would be appreciated.

Comment: there is no error  , i just don't have access to that specific the System.Linq dll 
wheni want to add a reference to it in my project.

Comment: Is this just behavior that you're seeing in Visual Studio? Otherwise it seems like you'd get a compile or runtime error...

Comment: it's a behavior i guess well a compile error isn't the right word 
i just want to expose functionality from system.Linq  
the .ToList<T>() Extesion Method.

Comment: Can you post the code you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure your Project is version 3.0 or higher.

Right Click on your project and then click add reference.

and maybe you are looking for this: **System.Data.Linq**

Check it here:

[System.Linq Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx)

[System.Data.Linq Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.aspx)

Best Regards

Comment: iv'e neglected to mention that iv'e already done that , but still even 
though the reference was added i can't for some reason add it in 
the using directive .

also : i wan't the namespace which give's me the .net 4.0 extentions 
like .ToList<T>()

Comment: that might work ... the problem is i need to build on this one .

Comment: of course , is your next question gonna be if i pressed save ?
if this wasn't a real wierd problem i wouldn't bother posting it.

Comment: correct...this is is weird where you don't have any problem if you create new project..have you tried to create simple linq query on its code behind?

Comment: iv'e tried using the .ToList() extention wich is not exposed.

Comment: ..When you tried to type .toList() is there any popups saying that you need to add any reference? var test = (from a in p select p).ToList()

Comment: @eran You're talking pretty snarky to someone who is trying to help you.  That's not cool.

Comment: Im just trying to help you @eran otzer. I didnt thought that you think of that.Sorry...we are here to ask questions and help co developers. not to ridicules someone..

Answer (score 13):

`System.Core` is the dll that the `System.Linq` namespace is in.  As long as you have a reference to `System.Core` in your project you should be able to do

```
using System.Linq;
```

in any source file in whcih you want to use the Linq methods.

Check under `References`  in the Solution Explorer.  If System.Core is not there then:

- Right-click References
- Click "Add Reference..."
- Choose System.Core from the .Net tab

Comment: iv'e done that from the get go .
iv'e stated that in my question.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since asking the question, but in case if anyone else is stuck, this solution may seem strange but worked for me: Change the the target framework from 4.0 to 3.5, rebuild it, then change it back to 4.0 and rebuild again.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to do both:

1 Manually reference System.Core in the project file if VS Studio referencing it throws an error

2 Add this line to web.config if not already there:

```
<add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Some of the references I had in my project did not seem to resolve when I added for example using System.Linq into my project even though all necessary namespaces were referenced.

It resolved when I removed "read only" from web.config file properties and rebuilt the project.